# At what frequency is /var/log/wtmp updated?

Tags: reboot

What daemon is in charge of updating this file and at what frequency does it run ?

When I type in `last reboot` I see :

```
reboot   system boot  3.5.0-45-generic Wed Jan 15 16:24 - 09:49 (14+17:24)  
reboot   system boot  3.5.0-45-generic Wed Jan 15 16:04 - 09:49 (14+17:45)
```

and one minute later I see that it changed too (09:49 -> 09:50) so I guess the file is updated frequently.

Also why in this case are there 2 'reboot' sessions active ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single daemon updating it. For normal logins one of the programs processing the login (getty/login, sshd, ftpd) is responsible for updating it.

On a reboot a new reboot entry is written and a timestamp is written for the old one. You see it 'changing' because it prints the time since boot up to now.

You probably didn't shutdown your machine correctly last time so the reboot entry wasn't updated to end at that time.